# Angular 7 DataTable: No data available after clicking on the table's header

Tags: angular, datatable

I'm working on getting a list of currencies in a DataTable, after configuring it according to https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/angular-way (angular way).

After implementation, on clicking the table's header cell , the datatable clears the data, knowing that it orders the data correctly if the rows where hard coded.

the following is my code:

HTML:

```
<table
  datatable
  [dtOptions]="dtOptions"
  [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"
  class="table-basic table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let currency of currencies">
      <td>{{ currency.Code}}</td>
      <td>{{ currency.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{ currency.NativeName }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Component

```
export class CoverageComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, OnInit         {

  @ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
  dtElement: DataTableDirective;

  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};

  currencies: Currency[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
        dom : ''
    };

          this.currencyService.getCurrencies().subscribe(
            (data: Currency[]) => {
              this.currency = data.slice(0, 5);

              // this.dtTrigger.next();
                  },
            (err : any) => {
              console.log("---> error", err);
            }
          );
        }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      this.dtTrigger.next();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
      // Do not forget to unsubscribe the event
      this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
    }

    rerender(): void {
        this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
        // Destroy the table first
        dtInstance.destroy();
        // Call the dtTrigger to rerender again
        this.dtTrigger.next();
      });
  }
```

**Question 1-** how to fix the column ordering problem on angular *ngFor binding approach
**Question 2-** is there a way to implement a custom text to order the rows. i tried jquery's datatable approach by adding data attributes (search and order)

```
 attr.data-search="{{currency.fullname}}"
 attr.data-order="{{currency.fullname}}"
```

Comment: please provide stackblitz example, it would be much easier to help.

Comment: @AmitBaranes thanks, i fixed the problem by removing   
   ngAfterViewInit() line
 , and  uncommenting  this.dtTrigger.next(); after subscribing to the http request.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by removing

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.dtTrigger.next();
}
```

and uncommenting

```
// this.dtTrigger.next();
```

after subscribing to the http request